# How to render React compoent or page in an jQuery project?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have an old jQuery project and now I want to add a div to the html file of the jQuery project and then render my own React components or pages to this div via the ReactDom.render method. If I create a new project with create-react-app, how do I configure it to render different components or pages in the jQuery project on demand while also enabling communication between the React component or page and jQuery? I don't have any ideas right now, has anyone solved a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [add-react-to-a-website](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html) on official documents, it's this what you want?

Comment: That's pretty much what I need, but if I create a new project with create-react-app to write the component code and a jQuery project to perform only the render operation, can the react project implement different component code packaged into different files?

Comment: You can't write components with CRA and consume in JQuery project, CRA is a SPA app.

Comment: You need to write your components in the JQuery project according to the official document, and transfer them via the babel tool

Comment: Is there a way to, for example, depending on the function, each function should have a render component, and by configuring webpack, compile the components corresponding to the different functions into different files, and then mount them on the window object, and in the jQuery project, I manually go and introduce the js files for these components, and then in the jQuery project pass the ReacDom. render method to display the different components.

Comment: sorry, i don't know what you mean, could you give an example to explain your idea?

Comment: The webpack compilation will be compiled into different files based on the different entrances, each file representing a component, and then the name of this component will be mounted on the window object, and then I'll take it in the jQuery project via the ReactDOM.render method according to the I then render the different components mounted on the window object in my jQuery project via the ReactDOM.render method, depending on the requirements.